# Linq Advanced Grouping + Count to new model

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I'm trying to write a linq operation to get back a list of Unique dates with grouped model info

So far i have this query contructed but i'm stuck on getting te correct output

```
var result = LogModels
 .Where(x => x.LogType.ToLower() == "error" && 
             x.LogLevel.ToLower() == "error")
 .GroupBy(inf => inf.ErrorCode)
 .Select(inf => Tuple.Create(inf.Key, inf.Count()))
 .ToList();
```

The output I'm trying to get is like this

PlaceHolder: ***26/07/2020***

[**Item 1**]
->>> Error   = A00.1 
->>> Message = Setup not correctly execeuted
->>> ErrorQty = 2 
[**Item 2**]
->>> Error   = A05.1 
->>> Message = Setup correctly installed
->>> ErrorQty = 1

PlaceHolder: ***27/07/2020***

[**Item 1**]
->>> Error   = A00.1 
->>> Message = Setup not correctly execeuted
->>> ErrorQty = 1 
[**Item 2**]
->>> Error   = A05.1 
->>> Message = Setup correctly installed
->>> ErrorQty = 1

### My Model Class

```
    public class LogModels
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string LogLevel { get; set; }
    public string LogType { get; set; }
}
```

Hope anyone can help me. 
Regards Me

Comment: Why don't you group by `Date` instead of `ErrorCode`? `.GroupBy(inf => inf.Date.Date)`

Comment: I only want to get a List of Dates with a unique model in it that show the total count of how much the error occurs and add the error message to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only want to get a List of Dates with a unique model in it that show the total count of how much the error occurs and add the error message to it

So you want to make groups of error LogModels that have the same Date, and from each group you want to count the number of Errors with the same ErrorCode.

Apparently every ErrorCode has exactly one Message. There are no combinations with the same ErrorCode and different message: So not: [ErrorCode X, Message 1] [ErrorCode X, Message 2]

Well, lets use the [overload of GroupBy that has a parameter ResultSelector:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__3_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__System_Func___1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____2__) We'll group your LogModels into Groups with same date, and subGroup them with the same ErrorCode:

```
var result = LogModels.Where(...).GroupBy(
    
    // parameter keySelector: make groups with same Date:
    logModel => logModel.Date,

    // parameter resultSelector: from every found date, and all LogModels with this date make 
    // make one new object:
    (date, logModelsWithThisDate) => new
    {
        PlaceHolder = date,

        // sub-group by ErrorCode:
        LogModels = logModelsWithThisDate.GroupBy(logModel => logModel.ErrorCode,

            // parameter resultSelector: from the errorCode,
            // and all logModels with this errorCode make one new:
            (errorCode, logModelsWithThisErrorCode) => new
            {
                Error = errorCode,

                // you know that all logModels with this ErrorCode have the same Message,
                // so you can take any LogModel to get the Message:
                Message = logModelsWithThisErrorCode
                    .Select(logModel => logModel.Message)
                    .FirstOrDefault(),

                ErrorQty = logModelsWithThisErrorCode.Count(),
            }),
    });
```

Alternatively you could sub-group on both ErrorCode and Message

```
.GroupBy(logModel => new
{
    ErrorCode = logModel.ErrorCode,
    Message = logModel.Message,
},
// ResultSelector:
(error, logModelsWithThisError) => new
{
    ErrorCode = error.ErrorCode,
    Message = error.Message,
    ErrorQty = logModelsWithThisError.Count(),
})
```

Although this works, and the result selector looks nicer, it is less efficient, because for every key it has to check both the ErrorCode and the Message, while you do know that if the x.ErrorCode equals y.ErrorCode, that x.Message will equal y.Message, so why check?

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Would not have found it without you!
Any good book you recommend on Linq?

Comment: Consider [The Standard Linq Operators](https://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx). To understand how LINQ works behind the lines: [Extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx). This also helps you to create a new LINQ method if you thin they forgot one that suits your needs. Sometimes a `foreach (...)` with a `yield return` is easier to understand than one big complex LINQ statement